# Travel to USA while working remotely to US company, long term (1-3 months)

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I work remotely for a US company, is it ok to go to the US for 1-3 months on a B1/B2 visa and continue working from there?
I won't be working ON my client, but I will still be working FOR them.

I've read before that going for meetings (1-2 weeks) is ok, but what about staying longer?

In practice I'm not going to the US because of the company, I won't meet them and that's not the purpose of my trip. I want to go as a tourist and spend 1-3 months there. I will just happen to be working remotely during this time.

Is this ok?

Answer (score 4):

*Depends*. Are you legally employed by the US company? If yes, I do not know but I suspect you would need a worker visa as there is no specific remote worker visa so B1/B2 makes me suspect this is not the case.

So I will readily presume you are legally employed by a company in your home country (which you might own) or simply self employed and have a contracting relationship or the US company owns the company you work for etc. In this case, my personal experience is that noone gives a damn: if asked at the border you can answer truthfully (and if you are well prepared, also prove) that you are employed by a company in country X. You will have hotel reservations and the plane ticket out of the country. That's enough. Never lie to a border officer and never offer information unasked.

Comment: I am self employed, working from brazil to US company as a contractor.