# Work remotely for a US employer - Travel to US on tourist visa - Work remotely from hotel/friends part time

Tags: visas, usa, work, taiwanese-citizens, tourism

My girlfriend is a Taiwanese citizen works for a US based company from Taiwan. She wants to visit me for up to 90 days on an ESTA tourist visa.

While shes here she wants to sightsee, hang out with me, and work part time remotely from the hotel/apartment, note that she is an independent contractor for her company.

Is working part-time somehow illegal? From my understanding this is incredibly vague and I have searched for hours for a similar situation but have not found anything. Any advice with experiences or links to US laws would be very much appreciated. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I believe Taiwanese citizens are eligible to visit the US under the Visa Waiver program; is there a particular reason she wants to get a B-2 visa?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong link before: I meant [this one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44683/travel-to-usa-while-working-remotely-for-us-company?rq=1).  Also https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44787/travel-to-usa-while-working-remotely-to-us-company-long-term-1-3-months?rq=1

Comment: Nate - She wants a B2 visa to visit me as well as some of her friends in CA as the main reason. The issue being she needs to continue to work remotely for her US based company as she usually does while she lives in her home country of Taiwan.

Comment: furthermore, I have looked at the link about the Ukrainian citizen but I dont believe that was relevant to this particular situation as he does not plan on working but does plan on meeting his company. As well as his stay is short.

Comment: She doesn't need a visa to _visit_ the US for up to 90 days. I don't know offhand about visiting Canada though, but even a US visa wouldn't help with visiting Canada.

Comment: on the contrary, my gf and I want her to stay for up to 90 days, and she will not be meeting any individuals related to work during this time. Only working remotely from her laptop at our residence. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue about working.  I am just wondering why she wants to apply for a B2 visa (costs $160) when tourism, business and visiting friends are also permitted under the visa waiver program (costs $14 for the ESTA application).  I don't think having a B-2 visa would make any positive difference for the work issue.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: CA might stand for California.

Comment: I suppose it was my misunderstanding about the B2 visa - she doesnt need one being a citizen of Taiwan, which is under the VWP, correct?

Comment: yes CA is california. my fault.

Comment: @EliGebler: Correct, that is what I was trying to say.

Comment: So yes she is going to obtain an ESTA. Then wants to work remotely while visiting. We would like to understand the legality of this if there are any problems. The second link you posted in the original comment is relevant and useful. It seems to be quite the gray area however.